# Fubini's theorem -integrability condition violated

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X_{1}=X_{2}=\mathbb{N}$ and let $\mu_{1},\mu_{2}$ be counting measures. Let $A=\{(k,k):k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ let $B=\{(k,k+1):k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ so A is the diagonal, B is off the diagonal. Let $f=\chi_{A}-\chi_{B}$

Why is

$\displaystyle\int_{X_{2}}(\int_{X_{1}}fd\mu_{1})d\mu_{2}))=1$

while

$\displaystyle\int_{X_{1}}(\int_{X_{2}}fd\mu_{2})d\mu_{1}))=0$

I suspect it might have something to do with the point $(0,0)$ where the characteristic function on $B$ is zero there.
Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Because when one computes each of these integrals, one finds 1 and 0 respectively. Did you try to compute, say, the inner integral in the first identity?

Comment: ah I solved it. Best it to draw a ''matrix'' to see the points and then sum along rows and columns instead. The values will be as in the above integrals : $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{N}} ( \int_{\mathbb{N}} f(n,m)\mbox{d}\mu_1) \mbox{d}\mu_2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty f(n,m) = 1 \neq 0 = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n,m) = \int_{\mathbb{N}} (\int_{\mathbb{N}} f(n,m) \mbox{d}\mu_2) \mbox{d}\mu_1$